# FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED deprecated. What to do now?

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I had a `LocationReceiver` which used `FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED` to extract a `Location` from an `Intent`. But now `KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED` is deprecated what should I change it to?

Current code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);

    if (location != null) {
        float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        Log.d(LocationReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "*** Accuracy is: " + accuracy + " ***");
    } else {
        Log.d(LocationReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "*** location object is null ***");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some research I found the answer:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            // use the Location
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this answer? I would like to see the context. Thanks!

Comment: Just explored [the api](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm getting false for `hasResult`. Any idea why?